# udp - client to multiple servers

Tags: c, udp

I have looked through many pages and forums, but still am unsure about this.  I am writing a project where the client reads in a txt file of numbers and sends the numbers to the server who will do some computation and send the result back to the client.  Is it possible to connect a client to multiple servers using udp?  and if so, an explanation would be nice.  I don't think I quite understand udp fully yet.  I am writing this in c also.  The reason for connecting to multiple servers from one client is because I need to run the client using 1, 2, 4, and 8 servers (distributing numbers to each server until none are left) and compare the run time.  Any quick help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UDP to multiple servers with the same socket. Probably the simplest way to do it is to have the client assign a session ID to each connection, include the session ID in each datagram it sends, and have the server return that session ID in each reply datagram it sends. Don't use the IP address to distinguish which server the packet is from because a server can have more than one IP address, making it unreliable.

Just remember that if you use UDP, you don't get any of the things TCP adds. If you need any of them, you need to do them yourself. If you need all or most of them, TCP is a *much* better choice. TCP does:

- Session establishment
- Session teardown
- Retransmissions
- Transmit pacing
- Backoff and retry
- Out of order detection and rearrangement
- Sliding windows
- Acknowledgments

If you need any of these things and choose to use UDP, you need to do them yourself.